Split one request into multiple controllers NestJS
I have a NestJS server deployed on AWS Lambda. I am integrating AWS SQS with larger batch sizes. This basically means that the Lambda handler is called with an array of requests (say 10) each containing their own request endpoint, body, headers.... The express-serverless app is started on the handler and the event passed to it. I cannot call the server for each request. Is there anyway to split the requests all to their respective endpoint/controller after passing them to the server?
I have tried using middlewares and interceptors, where I can, say, modify the URL to hit a controller dynamically, but only for one request. There is no way for me to send all the requests of the batch separately. I also can't find how to call a controller from another controller without doing an http-request,

Why dont you call the service rather than the controllers?
The initial request can be parsed to call corresponding services/ functions.

Yes that is a solution. However, I want the endpoints to be more general, for example be called by the APIGateway directly or by another microservice. I dont want to make duplicate controllers/services for each one.
